# Decide Laravel or Wordpress route in the index file

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I have an application which uses Laravel in combination with Wordpress.

Now Laravel has routes and also wordpress.

I want to check in the public/index.php if the url correspond with the Laravel route or Wordpress route.

So, something like this works, but i want to fill dynamicly the $laravelRoutes array, but at that level there is no database connection.

How can i achieve this correctly?

**public/index.php**

```
$actual_link = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$parts = explode('/',$actual_link);

$laravelRoutes = ['admin','rest'];
if (isset($parts[1])&& in_array($parts[1],$laravelRoutes) ){
    /**
     * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
     */
    require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
    $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
    $response = $kernel->handle(
        $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
    );
    $response->send();
    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
}else{
    /*
     // Loads the WordPress Environment and Template
    */
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
    require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp/wp-blog-header.php' );
}
```

Comment: How would one "combine" laravel and wordpress? They each have their own index.php entry file. Of course you can include 1 in another. But it feels like you might have created an unsafe monster of Frankenstein.

Comment: @ThomasMoors simple, use Laravel and place the wordpress in wp/ folder into the public and it works, no MONSTER :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
I am getting the routes from Laravel and check this.

```
$actual_link = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$parts = explode('/',$actual_link);

$laravelRoutes = ['zcalendar','rest'];
if (isset($parts[1])&& in_array($parts[1],$laravelRoutes) ) {
    /**
     * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
     */
    require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
    $app      = require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';
    $kernel   = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
    $response = $kernel->handle(
        $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
    );

    $app        = app();
    $routes     = $app->routes->getRoutes();
    $exceptions = ['{uri}', 'home', '/'];
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
        if (in_array($route->uri, $exceptions)) {
            continue;
        }
        $routePart = explode('/', $route->uri);
        if ($parts[1] == $routePart[0]) {
            $response->send();

            $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
        }
    }
}else{
    /*
     // Loads the WordPress Environment and Template
    */
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
    require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp/wp-blog-header.php' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution:

in **web.php**

```
// laravel route 1

// laravel route 2

Route::any('/{wordpress_slug}', function ($wordpress_slug) {

    require_once('wordpress/index.php');

});
```

That way it is easy to do everything from Laravel.

Comment: Does this actually work? Any dependencies like lumenpress/laravel?

Comment: @ScraperDave this works yes, because require is just plain php